# Is there a way to add_definitions for just a single language?

Tags: cmake, preprocessor

CMake provides [`add_compile_definitions()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_compile_definitions.html#command:add_compile_definitions) for adding compiler definitions for all targets in the current directory; and there is also `target_compile_definitions()` for individual targets. But - it seems to me like the general case should be language-specific, not absolutely all targets. Why would, say, C and Rust use the same definitions?

So - is there some way to add a definition to all targets of a single language, other than one-at-a-time?

Comment: What for? To allow a crazy mix of languages and targets in the same directory? If that's your project structure, CMake isn't going to be your biggest problem.

Comment: @Friedrich: What do you mean by "crazy mix"? Is it crazy to use more than one language?

Comment: @Tsyvarev: Yes it is, I forgot about that one.

Comment: @einpoklum no, I never wrote that. I would aim for a project structure which cleanly separates targets and targets of different languages. A lack of structure may create the need you asked about. Adding CMake code that invisibly and implicitly changes behavior instead of fixing the root cause may make things even worse. This is what I called crazy. I don't know your project so whatever.

Comment: @Friedrich: Sometimes your project has example programs - often with a single file - in different languages. You can't "cleanly separate" them.

Comment: I voted to reopen because compile options are not the same as compile definitions. If we want to have a canonical, we should write a general question about how to make variable values / target properties differ based on the compile language of the target they eventually get attached to.

Comment: @user: "compile options are not the same as compile definitions" - But they are very similar. Changing them uses very similar commands and properties. I don't think that we need two separate Q/A which answers resembles one another (and some answers, like ones about CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS, even duplicate each other).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`add_compile_definitions`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_compile_definitions.html) at the top of the top-level CMakeLists.txt file (or whichever variable scope you want this to apply to) with the `$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:languages>` [generator expression](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html) (requires `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)`). Ex.

```
add_compile_definitions("$<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:C,CXX>:-DFOO>")
```

If your `cmake_minimum_required` is less than 3.3, I suppose you could [append](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/list.html#append) to [`CMAKE_<LANG>_FLAGS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_FLAGS.html). Ex.

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -DFOO=bar")
```

Comment: **SPECIAL NOTICE** that `add_definition` doesn't support generator expression; only `add_compile_definition` support it. See [here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/15374) for discussions.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your language is MYLANG and definitions are passed to the compiler using `-DFOO=bar` on the command-line. This should do what you asked for:

```
set(CMAKE_MYLANG_FLAGS "${CMAKE_MYLANG_FLAGS} -DFOO=bar")
```

... but it's rather ugly.